# How to read a JSON file in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am just looking for advice as to "how can i read a JSON file into PostgreSQL.

I don't have any permissions to create tables so I was wondering:
Is it possible to read a JSON file from a specified file path to query it? (Kind of like how you can read a CSV file in pandas with Python?)

I reviewed the [Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/files/documentation/pdf/13/postgresql-13-A4.pdf) but it was confusing to grasp. Thanks for any advice or support

Comment: As SQL is executed on the server, it can't access any files on the client (that sent the SQL). And unfortunately, `psql` does not have such a feature either. You will either need a third party tool or write your own script/program.

Comment: Perhaps you can create temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks Both of you for the Input! @a_horse_with_no_name I believe your feedback is correct! Will further investigate!